# PHP7 netbeans 8.1 debugger support needed, How to make it work?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug, php-7

I use Netbeans 8.1 for developing in PHP, lately I installed **PHP7** and xDebug doesn't works anymore.
I love working with Netbeans and I need to work with PHP 7.

Is there any way to configure Netbeans and Apache to support debugging?
(I installed XAMPP with PHP 7)

I looked into those sited but with no luck:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html
http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

As I understand PHP7 doesn't support xdebug but if you somehow managed to make it work please share with me.

Comment: Xdebug >= 2.4 supports PHP 7, perhaps check your installed version?

Comment: How can I check the Xdebug version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to download xdeubg for php7, select a version matched your php version.
https://xdebug.org/download.php

my setting as following:

```
zend_extension = "c:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:/xampp/tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1100
```

xdebug work well for me.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

First versions of xdebug for php7 wouldn't work for me. More recent version did work.

Here is my currently working conf php7 / xdebug / netbeans:

```
    Client
    Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
    Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
    Java: 1.8.0_60; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.60-b23
    Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_60-b27
    System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; fr_FR (nb)

    Server
    Apache : 2.4.18-win64-VC14
    PHP Version 7.0.3RC1
    Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition AMD64

    php.ini
    [xdebug]
    zend_extension = <php_install_path>/ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
    xdebug.remote_enable = On
    xdebug.remote_host=<my_IP_(using_VPN)>
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
    output_buffering=off
    xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time=360000
```

In Netbeans I did set Path Mapping values

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and I have the latest PHP 7.0.4 and netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I installed new version of Netbeans 8.1 and I spent a lot of time looking for solution for debugging php 7, so maybe I will share my configuration:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension ="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
output_buffering=off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time=360000
```